# How to install realtime kernel on Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: usb, kernel, realtime

I am using Ubuntu Live USB stick 16.04.1 with boot toram and persistence option.
So far best sounding setup for audio streaming (Firefox+AdobeFlash+Tidal). It is also best setup in terms of usability and user experience. For me far better than Volumio 2 and Daphile in this regard.
Ubuntu Live USB uses generic kernel. I would like to try out realtime kernel. I do not want to install Ubuntu. I want Ubuntu Live USB with realtime kernel.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Installing the new kernel is straightforward, but using it is the problem.  The default kernel is already in use by the time you can start doing anything interesting.  The new ISOs have filesystem ISO9660, so you cannot easily modify them (like putting in a new kernel).  An easy workaround is possible for UEFI machines using grub to boot -- put a FAT32 filesystem on your target, and just copy the contents of the ISO there.  Then modify the grub boot command to eliminate the preseed business (because the FAT filesystem cannot have the "ubuntu" link).

Just copying all the files from the ISO to a FAT filesystem, would result in a working UEFI boot, but the missing link capability results in kernel arguments like "file="/cdrom/preseed/..." which do not name existing files. Replace the /cdrom... with the below after the boot=casper item:

persistent live-media-path=/casper/   ignore_uuid

Try with the existing kernel first, then replace it with the new one.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. It actually works, but I lost persistence. Do you know how to fix that?